# Memory leak in Apache Beam Python ReadFromPubsub IO

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**Overview**

We have a Dataflow streaming pipeline that reads messages from a pubsub subscription, transforms the dict to a dataclass and writes the data to postgres. I noticed that occasionally, pubsub throughput will go to zero. During this time, max memory utilization is typically at 95+%, though most of the time, data still flows through steadily despite memory being at 95+%.

[image]

**Debugging Steps**

To debug the issue, I slowly deleted PTransforms one bye one (from bottom to top), deployed it and observed. The issue persisted throughout all setups, even when the entire pipeline **was just a single `ReadFromPubsub` transform and nothing else**. This makes me suspect that it could be a memory leak in the library implementation.

**Observations / Comments**

- The falling edge of the memory typically corresponds to a scaling event. During scaling events from 1->2 workers, we've also noticed that if we initially had worker A only, sometimes it ends up having workers B and C, instead of A and B. Does this mean that Dataflow is aware that worker A was having mem issues and as such decided to shut it down?

  - Other times, the falling edge corresponded to a restart of worker A. This also clears memory.
- This issue was also raised in another forum, with this [response](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Dataflow-memory-usage-never-stops-increasing/m-p/597926/highlight/true#M1993) suggesting windowing as a solution. This is my attempt at understanding what the author means in a hand wavy way - In a streaming pipeline that only uses a global window (my case), DoFns don't get a chance to garbage collect as they are permanently "on"? (`teardown` is never called?) As such, we need to give it a gap and we can force this by creating windows (though the logic after that will be cumbersome - something like window into a 5 seconds window, fire repeatedly when there's 1 element and finally a group by key and flattening the results again. basically a no-op just that we want to force windowing in)

**Setup**

- Apache beam version - `2.48.0`
- Python version - `3.9.14`
- Runner - `Dataflow`

Comment: Hi leech, can you follow this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#memory-use)  Maybe this will help you in memory utilization ? and also share more details if you are facing any errors ?

Comment: There are no errors logged whatsoever. The pipe I am testing with now is literally one that reads from pubsub and **does nothing else**, but despite that, memory still steadily increases.

I'm running it on a n1-standard-2 machine now. After 2 days, it has crept up to 3.4 GB of mem util. I'm waiting for it to hit 90% util in around 10 more days, after which, dataflow eng team agreed that they will look into it as that is sufficient evidence.

Comment: Hi @leech, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have identified the leak, https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28246 has details and workarounds.